# iOS / Beacon: Reset didEnterRegion possible?

Tags: ios, location, ibeacon

We ned the location manager of the iOS to detect beacons. This mean we monitor a region and get the didEnterRegion event if we enter into a region. Now it is difficult to test our beacon installation because we have to wait for the didExitRegion event for about 30 seconds at least. Sometimes it goes longer than the 30 seconds...

It would be very helpful if we can cancel the entry into a region. To be sure we are out.

Is that possible?
Is there a way to do that?

Thanks
Hans

Answer (score 1):

You can simply stop monitoring for a beacon region, then immediately restart monitoring.  In my experience, this will send a new `didEnterRegion:` callback when a beacon matching the region is next detected, typically within a second or so.

```
locationManager.stopMonitoring(for: region)
locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)
```

Note also that you can programmatically restart all monitored regions with:

```
for region in locationManager.monitoredRegions {
  locationManager.stopMonitoring(for: region)
  locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)
}
```